# SharePoint REST API - set WelcomePage

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to set the welcome page of a SharePoint site using the REST API.
Here's my code:

```
def request_digest(self, site_url):

    api_call = "/_api/contextinfo"
    url = f"{site_url}{api_call}"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {str(self.O365_TOKEN)}",
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
    return data['d']['GetContextWebInformation']['FormDigestValue']
    
    

def set_homepage(self, site_url):

    RequestDigest = self.request_digest(site_url)


    api_call = "/_api/Web/RootFolder"

    url = f"{site_url}{api_call}"

    payload = {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.Folder"
                },
                "WelcomePage": "SitePages/Home.aspx"
            }
    headers = {
        "X-HTTP-Method":"PATCH",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {str(self.O365_TOKEN)}",
        "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-length": str(len(json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8'))),
        "X-RequestDigest": RequestDigest,
        "IF-MATCH": "*"
        }
    
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

And here's the response:

{"error": {"code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException", "message": "Invalid request"}}

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried:

- searching but every source (there's really not many...) says that this should work. I even tried Fiddler to inspect the header and payload but the only difference I've found that I'm using OAUTH token instead of x-requestdigest.
- without and with the X-RequestDigest header because it was not clear if I have to include it or not when using OAUTH token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#writing-data-by-using-the-rest-interface)
- requests.patch instead of requests.post
- other API calls GET and POST are working fine, I'm able to create new site, get its properties etc...

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code to set WelcomePage

```
function SetDefaultPage() {
    $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/rootfolder",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': {
                    // Type that you are modifying.
                    'type': 'SP.Folder'
                },
 
                'WelcomePage': 'SitePages/home.aspx'
            }),
            headers:
        {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
}
```